Is it possible to affect spin probability of an entangled particle?
Say I have entangled particles A and B. Assuming we are talking about photons, we have 50/% chance of particle A being spin up.
Is it possible to affect the probability of particle A to be spin up greater or less than 50% of the time?
Can I do some kind of rotation/operation on the particle A by itself to affect it's probability to be something like 51/49 chance of being spin up?

The question's not really clear, because you seem to be mainly talking about A being in some superposition of polarization (spin) states. Its entanglement with B seems incidental to the question. Can you clarify? Are you asking about somehow doing local operations on system A while "not affecting the state" of system B? And if so, given that they are entangled, what do you mean by "not affecting the state" of system B? Do you want to do a local operation on A that leaves the reduced density matrix of B unchanged? We need some clarification here before we can answer the question, I think.

@march Yes a local operation on 2 entangled particles A and B that would affect the probability of the entire system.
Ex: An operation that changes the probability of A to 51/49 for spin up and B to 51/49 for spin down.
Does that make any sense?

I'm still confused, because in your comment, you say "a local operation on 2 entangled particles A and B", but by "local operation" I meant something that acts only of one of the components, i.e., just an system A. Which do you want? In addition, if you want both A and B probabilities to change, make sure that's clear in your question! (In your question, you only mention the probabilities of measurements on A.)

@march 2 entangled photons. Is it possible to skew the probability of spin up/down from 50/50 to something like 51/49 or 70/30?
Is there anyway to do this?

James with spin polarisers.

Of course you can "prepare states" using photons that used to be in different states.

@march It's okay if you don't know :)

No it is not possible due to randomness .... if you only have 2 random states then its always 50/50.  Like flipping a coin there is no way to unbalance the coin when it comes to atoms/bbo crystals. If you used a slightly misaligned polarizer on one of the outputs you could randomly affect transmission ... but then you lose one of the pair.

@PhysicsDave Read my answer to see how to achieve an intentional bias. Most Bell tests use polarizing beams splitters rather than polarizers. That way both photons in each pair are detected.

@DrChinese Yes that's cool.  You are able to skew a population of photons. Maybe somehow in the future we'll find a crystal with a biased output.

The simple answer to your question is Yes.  You can create 51/49 polarization, or 52/48 polarization, or whatever mixture you might care to produce.
This can easily be seen in production of Type I entangled photon pairs. For this type, 2 BBo crystals are used. Each thin crystal generates VV pairs that are not polarization entangled. They are placed in line with each other, but one is rotated 90 degrees relative to the other so it is producing HH pairs. When down conversion occurs, it can have occurred from either crystal. You won’t know which though. This places the output in a 50/50 superposition of VV>+HH> which is fully entangled. See figure 1.a. in either of the following papers by Kwiat et al:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9810003
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4182
So far so good. Now, if the 2 crystals are oriented say 75 degrees relative to each other (instead of 90 degrees), they will produce pairs that are distinctly more VV> than HH>. They will be polarization entangled, but not maximally so. By suitable rotation, you can achieve the desired mixture.
However: as you dial the mixture away from 50/50, the entanglement quality changes accordingly.
Edited to add/clarify: Alice cannot do anything to A to change the marginal probability that Bob sees for his B photons. That is strictly a function of how the initial pairs are created.

How would you even get an electron pair with 49% spin up and 51% spin down? You can’t—and there’s no reason to, either. Now, with photons, it’s a different story. You can certainly have photon pairs that aren’t perfectly aligned, maybe off by a degree or two in polarization. But that’s not ideal; it’s an experimental glitch—what we call a detection loophole. This is exactly the kind of problem French physicist Alain Aspect worked tirelessly to eliminate.

@BillAlsept There is no theoretical reason you can’t get electrons to have a bias, but I don’t personally know a way to do that. With photon pairs, as I mentioned, you can get any mixture you care to - with the resulting trade-off in entanglement. This method is not a loophole, because you would purposefully set the angle as desired. Of course, most of the time you want maximal entanglement. BTW this is not an example of the detection loophole because both photons are in fact detected.

I think two cases have to be distinguished. Assume that the entangled particles $A$ and $B$ are sent to Alice and Bob, respectively. We assume that Alice and Bob are far away, i.e., the time for light to travel from Alice to Bob or vice versa is longer than the time our experiments take.

Can Alice do anything to change the marginal probabilities of Bob? E.g., change the frequencies of Bob from $50/50$ to $45/56$. The answer to this is no. If Alice makes a "spin measurement" in the same direction as Bob, and she measures down than with $100?%$ certainty Bob will measure up. So, the conditional probability is affected by Alice. But Alice has no control over the outcome of her measurement. Therefore, in the long run, Bob's probability is still $50/50$.

Can Bob do something to change the probability for spin measurements on particle $B$? The answer is yes. One may use, for example, a liquid crystal to change the polarization of the particle. This may rotate the state from a superposition to an eigenstate of the spin operator.
This is more or less the way LCDs work. By changing the polarization, they change the probability of light going through the second polarization.


On the EPR-argument: The point of the EPR argument was that Quantum mechanics violates locality. The measurement done by Alice instantaneously changes the state of Bob's particle from a superposition to either spin up or spin down with $50/50$ probability. This is not the same as if you put a pair of shoes in two boxes and send one to Alice and one to Bob (this was also explained by John Bell). The difference is that according to standard quantum mechanics, there exists no fact about spin up or down prior to the "measurement." Einstein's hope was to replace quantum mechanics with a local theory in which the outcome of the spin measurement is already decided (as for the shoes in the boxes) so one can get rid of the spooky action at a distance.
John Bell showed that this is not possible. I.e., even if you add "hidden-variables" to the description, you cannot get a local theory.

Bell showed proof of no hidden variables, not that a local theory is impossible.  The common sense belief adopted by most scientists is that the photons spins are created at the time of photon creation, thus no FTL.

@PhysicsDave I dissagree. I cannot say if it is the belief of most scientist that the spin of photons are created at the time of photon creation. But if this is the case, then most scientist are wrong. This is the whole point of the Bell inequality. John Bell himself explained it very clearly. Bell was a great critic of "no hidden variables proofs".

Yes, absolutely no hidden variables, electrons in atoms are much too fast and highly random.  But no hidden variables does not rule out local processes as long as they are random .... in pair production it is random which is up and which is down .... but always there is one up and one down.

Forget about the term "entangled" and just focus on correlated particles. For electrons, the terms "spin up" or "spin down" are common. When it comes to photons, though, the main parameter for correlation is polarization. But perfectly correlated photons need more than polarization. There are other variables, including frequency, trajectory, and timing. All of these factors ensure that later measurements line up accurately.
As for your question about the 51/49% split, it doesn’t really apply here because, in electron experiments, measurements only register as spin up or spin down. Before the measurement the electron could have been at some arbitrary angle, but if it registers as "up," it’s because its angle skewed more towards "up." Same goes for down if the spin already leaned toward the down. Keep in mind that electron experiments like the Stern-Gerlach experiment create a magnetic field that pulls the electrons up or down depending on which way the electrons orientation was already skewed.
You would want these correlations—or anti-correlations—to be as close to perfect as possible. That’s the whole point of EPR: perfect correlation. Photon pairs need to have all variable perfectly correlated and if their polarizations are off by 1 degree as you suggest, then the whole experiment is faulty and later measurement would mean nothing. The whole point of PERFECTLY correlating them is to have something to later measure against, or to compare to.

As mentioned in my answer, you can have entanglement even with an intentional bias.
